# Google App Maker - Creating a contract. Methods to use?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am trying to make a contract in Google App Maker. This contract features text boxes for people to enter their names. The issue I ran into is that it's not enough to just add the person to a SQL database, but there needs to be solid digital evidence of the person signing the contract.

Using 'ctrl' + 'p' on the appmaker script messes up the formatting of the page.

I see that there is an [appmaker sample of how to create a PDF](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/email-pdf), however, this just creates a new document and then adds text to it. There is a lot of text in the contract and it is specifically formatted, so typing that up in a Google Doc through javascript would take hours.

Does anyone with experience with appmaker know of an easier method? Or is the one I found really the best?

Comment: Presumably your 'Contract' has the same language for everyone that may be filling out the information via the text boxes? If that is the case you can set up a Google Docs template with all the text of the contract and everywhere you will need a textbox field entered into the document you can create a placeholder like '<<MyTextboxField>>'. In your model onAfterCreate event you could then use the DocsService, call your template and make a copy of it and then find each instance of a placeholder named specifically to your record fields and replace them with the actual record value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing...

1. Create a template google document with a certain identifier {} in places where information must be loaded into (ex. name, address, phone number...)
2. In appmaker, create a script which read the contract and filled out all the identifiers {} with the relevant information
3. In appmaker, there run the command to turn a google document into a pdf
4. In appmaker, email that pdf to the relevant person